# Check my work on permutations of letters

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> In how many arrangements can the word "CORONA" be arranged in only 4 letters with no restriction?

I divided into 2 cases:

Case 1: No doubles, hence we have 1 C, 1 O, 1 R, 1 N and 1 A to arrange into 4 spaces, so 5P4, in other words 5!.

Case 2: one double, we have a double O, to arrange into 4 spaces with repetition, so $\frac{4P2}{2!}$ and the rest of the letters C, R, N and A, to be arranged in the 2 remaining spaces, hence $\frac{4P2}{2!}\cdot 4P2$

So the final answer will be adding both: $\frac{4P2}{2!}\cdot 4P2+5!=192$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In how many arrangements can the word "CORONA" be arranged in only 4 letters with no restriction?

Yes your work is both accurate and valid.  However, I found it a bit confusing.

I would have worded it this way.

$\underline{\text{case 1: 0 O's}}$ 
4! ways to permute the C, R, N, A. 
4!

$\underline{\text{case 2: 1 O}}$ 
$\binom{4}{3} = 4$ ways to choose the other three letters. 
Then, 4! ways to permute the O with the other 3 letters. 
$4 \times 4!$

$\underline{\text{case 3: 2 O's}}$ 
$\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to choose the other two letters. 
Then, $4 \times 3 = 12$ ways to place the other two letters. 
$6 \times 12$

Final answer:

$$(4!) + (4 \times 4!) + (6 \times 12).$$